# How can I debug failed tests in guile source installation?

Tags: installation, scheme, guile

I'm building `GNU guile-2.0.0` from its source code on an old RHEL6.6 machine. It seems to be built successfully, but I got the following error when I run `make check`. As I'm very new to `scheme` and `guile`, I have no idea how to find any reason for this fail.

How can I debug this? Where can I find any clue to this?

```
....
Running ports.test
Running posix.test
FAIL: posix.test: utime: valid argument (second resolution)
Running print.test
Running procprop.test
....

Totals for this test run:

passes:                 34320
failures:               1
unexpected passes:      0
expected failures:      31
unresolved test cases:  15
untested test cases:    5
unsupported test cases: 9
errors:                 0

FAIL: check-guile
```

Comment: The source is [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=guile.git;a=blob;f=test-suite/tests/posix.test;h=4dadd7784b196aab318d27ea10d609f9c6c0844c;hb=HEAD). `utime` sets file access timestamps. It's not setting them to the given values for some reason, but the actual error isn't being shown.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for your comment. As I'm building it from source, I have the source too. However, I cannot guess what can be a problem from the source. Do you know where I can find details about test failures?

Comment: That test seems bonkers to me. It compares file-times with current time. But the time between setting file-times and reading system-time may be nonzero. Besides, not all systems updates atime. Just ignore the test result and be happy